# Configure graphics driver for Arch Linux on Lenovo Z710

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, arch-linux, display-driver

I want to configure my graphics card driver on Lenovo Z710, because my laptop is overheating. On Ubuntu I installed bumblebee and other stuff, but my system crashed; this time I want to avoid this.

My system: Intel 4th Generation, Nvidia GeForce 840M.

I would like to have a [hybrid graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hybrid_graphics) system,
and not just use my Intel graphics card and switch the Nvidia off.

Has anybody tried to do this, and is it quite stable?